# How to use x.509 or x509 certificate in docusign and get secure date in callback

Tags: docusignapi, x509

I created a servlet application which receives post request and given that url in DocuSign connect and I am receiving data on any sign, or any event on DocuSign. But now I want to secure the call back data with x509 option in DocuSign connect.

I am use java application to data. let me know if any body explored this process